# How to generate HOG feature vector in java for SVM alogrithm

Tags: java, image-processing, machine-learning, svm

I am using SVM algorithm for image classification. Currently I am using pixels strength of gray-scaled images as feature vector. I want to use HoG feature vector for better results but I couldn't find a java library for getting HoG feature vector from image.

Comment: What kind of images are you trying to recognize? Pixel-value as a feature is reasonable method for letters/pictogram recognition but not real object images. Are you sure HoG will help you?

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz I want to recognize if there is a human presence in an image or not.

Comment: OK, than using pixel-values are definitively a wrong feature. HOG could help.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about smaller libraries but I'm certain that OpenCV has HOG and Java support. Here is the relevant documentation: http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/objdetect/HOGDescriptor.html